# credit card type and number validation in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I would like to run a program that matches the credit card type with entered number i.e when i select a card type from select,if card type matches with the entered number the image of the card should be loaded.I have used switch case with if and else inside case.When i run the code only else part is working.

What i need is it should display alert message as valid card and image of card should be displayed if not it should give alert as invalid card.Here is my code below..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function validate() 
                {
       var a = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
       var b = document.getElementById("cardno").value;
       var v = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;   
       var e = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;   
       var j = /^(?:(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/;
       var element = document.getElementById("img1");
       var element1 = document.getElementById("img2");
       var element2 = document.getElementById("img3");
       var card=a;
       switch(card){
       case "visa":
       if (b == v) 
                {
                alert("valid");
                element.src="images/visa.jpg";
        
       } else {
        
        alert("Invalid card number,Should start with 4");
     
       }
                break;
       case "ae":
       if (b == e) {
                    alert("valid");
        element1.src="images/ae.jpg";
       } else {
        alert("Invalid card number,Should start with 34 or 37 ");
       }
       break;
       case "jcb":
       if (b == j) {
                    alert("valid");
        element2.src="images/jcb.jpg";
       } else
       {
        alert("Invalid card number,Should start with 2131
or 1800");
       }
       break;
       default:
        alert("Enter valid card numbers");
       }
      }
     </script>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>User Form</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: palegreen">
    <div align="left" height="50%" width="40%">
<form action="user" method="post">
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td><label>UserName:</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="uname"
          placeholder="Enter username" required><br> <br></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><label>cardname:</label></td>
         <td><select id="mySelect">
           <option value="">SelectCard</option>
           <option value="visa">Visa</option>
           <option value="ae">AmericanExpress</option>
           <option value="jcb">Jcb</option>
         </select><br> <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><label>cardnumber:</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="nom" id="cardno" maxlength="16"
          pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" title="Enter Valid Card No"
          placeholder="Enter Card number" onkeypress="validate()" required><br>
          <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><label>Date Of Expiry:</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="doe" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"
          required><br> <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><label>Bill Due Date:</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="dat" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"
          required><br> <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Add"
          style="height: 30px; width: 100px" class="glowing-border"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
     </div> 
     <img src="images/visa.jpg" id="img1" align="right" height="40"
      width="50">
     <img src="images/ae.jpg" id="img2" align="right" height="40" width="50">
     <img src="images/jcb.jpg" id="img3" align="right" height="40"
      width="50">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can remove all your IF and ELSE statements and move the ELSE part to switch default case.

Comment: Thank you,if i remove if and else statements how come number entered in textbox matches with the regular expression.

Comment: With your current logic I think then you can change IF conditions like if(v.test("b"))  and if(e.test("b")) and if(j.test("b")).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `RegExp` objects with strings, which wont work.
I'm guessing that you wish to test the strings with the regular expressions. That is not done with the comparator (`== || ===`) but rather by calling the `test` method on the regexp object passing the string to test as a argument, as such:

```
let regexpObj = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;
if (regexpObj.test("a string")) {
  // If the method returns true, its a match, else its not a match.
}
```

I recommend reading the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) about regexp.